# Do vague comment prompts and tooltips encourage rambling on Politics.SE?

Tags: discussion, comments

Users can't resist general commenting on an answers' political orientation.  Other users can't resist commenting on those comments, which are then treated as a user forum.  Later, when this "forum" fails to have much relevant content, the comment-forum is deleted, with a warning about how comments are just for improving questions and answers.

Since there is a lag time between chatty comments being posted and moderators zapping them, this turns the comments into *de facto* short duration tweets.

So user and moderator time is wasted, and sometimes useful comments are lost in the cleanup.

Perhaps one cause of all this is the fuzziness of that directive found below questions and answers *"add a comment"*.  To save everyone's time, can this directive be made more explicit?  That is, change the word "comment" to something like:

- constructive comment
- comment to clarify specific facts in this answer

Comment: Related: [Should Politics SE ask to be part of the suggest Improvement experiment](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3451/101)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should Politics SE ask to be part of the suggest Improvement experiment](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3451/should-politics-se-ask-to-be-part-of-the-suggest-improvement-experiment)